# Broken Default App Association

Tags: pantheon-terminal, code

I recently accidentally deleted my sources list, but have successfully rebuilt. However, all default application like scratch, pantheon terminal, seemed to lose its default application association.

For exampl, ife i click edit on filezilla, it says can't find scratch in /usr/bin, or if i use ssh bookmark manager, it says it can't find pantheon-terminal.

Is there anyway to fix these (what i assume to be) symlink, or is it best to just reinstall?

Comment: Does it work in a guest session?